# Flowchart Design

Tags: python, flowchart

I need help designing a flowchart about a program thats gets a string from the user in main and then creates a function that takes a string as an argument and returns the sum of the elements (all elements in the array) in the string. And it displays the results in main by displaying the string and the length of the series. If somebody could just help me get started I would be very grateful!

Comment: I am confused about what you are asking. Do you want to know more about which tools you can use to create a flowchart? Do you have no experience at all in making flowcharts and you need help creating one? Or do you need more practical help and want the finished flowchart? Also why does this question have 'python' as a tag? Is the program you want to get a flowchart for in python?

Comment: Yes its for Python and I am just scratching the surface of it I am not very adept in this yet so yes flowcharts are about where im at. Im needing help developing the flowchart not the code to write the program. Sorry for the lack of information or effort I really am quite new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, flowcharts are language independent, so there was no need to tag this with python.  What's more, they tend to be very imperative in nature, so some of the more expressive features of Python may be denied you.

Are you sure it's a flowchart you need, or is it just an algorithm?

If it's a flowchart, then do this.  Imagine you are doing this manually.  What are the steps you need to take to accomplish this?  Don't worry about language features, just imagine in plain language, the various steps and information you need.  Once you have that, then you put it in diagram form.

Flowcharts have a few symbols that you need to get familiar with; otherwise, they're pretty intuitive.  Here's a Wiki to get you started:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart